# How can I get type information about a type created using the type provider framework

Tags: f#, type-providers

I created a type provider for an excel table.  I need to be able to reflect on this type to get info about its methods and properties. I can't figure out a way to do so.

```
type STable = Tables.DTable< @"Book1.xlsx", "Sheet1">

let t = typeof<STable>
```

I was hoping that t would would have information about the methods and properties of STable but it only returns information about System.Object.

How can I get info about the STable type?

Answer (score 2):

At runtime, `STable` isn't a real .NET type - it's erased down to some other type (`obj` in this case) - this is just how (erasing) type providers work.  If you absolutely need to get the type programmatically, then it's possible to do it using the raw type provider API, but this will be pretty ugly.  To do this, get an instance of the `ITypeProvider` (just like the compiler does behind the scenes), and then navigate the resulting namespaces and types until you get the `System.Type` instance you're looking for.